# AngularJS Access $scope in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I execute the following function when a page is executed:

```
$scope.displayTags = function(Id) {
    $scope.toogleSelectionBlocs = function selectionB(b) {
          // I have a checkbox to check...
    }

   $scope.showHello() {
       console.log("HELLO WORLD!");
   }
}
```

Then I have an other checkbox: (same controller but other function)

```
$scope.checkClick = function(){
    if($scope.mycheckbox == true){
        $scope.showHello();
    }
}
```

I have the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.checkClick (....)
```

How I can fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your function thats should be:

```
$scope.showHello = function() {
     console.log("HELLO WORLD!");
 }
```

and another thing why do you write the function inside another function, you should move the $scope.showHello to the outside of the $scope.displayTags

Answer (score 2):

1) $scope.showHello is missing the "=function(params){ .... } " part. (That should solve the problem you asked for)

2) Can you post more of your controller code to make clear what you are actually trying to do - the code looks a bit strange to me. (e.g. the "= function selectionB(b) {" part.